# Calling Reporting services rdl in Java application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have developed my reports in SQL REporting services and deployed in my server. I need to display the reports in my java application page. I want to know is there any control (like .net report viewer control) to display this

Thanks
balaweblog

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about a control, but if you just need to display reports and not provide much interaction you could use the report server web service and call it's render method.  This would allow you to execute and return the report output in a number of formats.  So you could have java code accepting parameters which you then pass to the Render method and you get back a byte array of a pdf that displays the report.

Render method...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258532(SQL.80).aspx

Reporting Services Webservice...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa274396(SQL.80).aspx