# Exposing Sql Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 over Extranet while integrating with Java web application with LDAP authentication

Tags: java, reporting-services, ldap, integration

As part of a development project I need to Integrate SSRS 2008 R2 with a Java application and expose to Internet/Extranet. The additional requirement is that we have LDAP authentication, so ideally when a user logs in to the webapp it gets authenticated to LDAP and when he clicks on Reports link in the Web App, he should get authenticated to the SSRS as well (more like a SSO) without asking any credentials. The reports should not loose any interactive features like Drill down, pagination, charts, sorting etc. Also there shouldn't be much overload on the Webfront as we have limited resource there.

I have gone through the below articles from Microsoft site where they have mentioned that we can expose SSRS configured in Report Manager Mode over Intranet. This I am already aware of and I know it works well with .net Platform. But what I need clarification is that when we integrate with Web developed in Java Platform whether this will work.  Since I am not from a Web background I am not sure how Java integration will happen. If you feel that Java integration will not be problem/ I have missed something let me know.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159272(v=sql.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345248(v=sql.105).aspx

http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/SQL-Server-2008-Reporting-Services-for-Internet-deployment

We can expose Report Manager to extranet, but we need to write custom security extension for Form Based Authentication. But this will work more as a standalone  application and will not be integrated with our web application. So user may have to login separately which may not be ideal.

So  I was exploring  at other alternate option like using SSRS web service to integrate with Java.

The articles what I was going through was based on web service some of them are given below

[Calling Reporting services rdl in Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142690/calling-reporting-services-rdl-in-java-application)

http://blog.ponytailbob.com/2012/04/ssrs-reporting-in-java-web-site.html

http://javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2005/jw-0110-sqlrs.html?page=1

Couple of issues that we could face -

1. The report comes as an html – It looses lot of interactive features like Sorting, Drill through etc which are part of our reporting requirements of the project
2. We loose pagination and incremental fetch in reporting
3. We may end up taking additional effort in Web front if we want bring tool bars etc from reporting .
4. They have mentioned that Images can be passed from SSRS to Java but we are not sure that Charts and other Graphs will be coming as static or it will can be generated dynamically.

Any help will be sincerely appreaciated.

Vyshak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1

---

Call Reporting Services (RS) Web service from your Java App. Your app could be on LDAP Auth but your RS instance could continue to be on Windows Auth, You need to generate Windows Auth using Java App while calling RS web service. You can generate disconnected report in HTML and show it to end users. In this case, Your RS would never be exposed to end users and communication between users and Reports would happen via your app. You would loose some additional features of RS like on demand rendering etc.

Option 2

---

Have your Reporting Services(RS) setup on Custom Authentication using your own authentication extension. Your java app would authenticate the user using LDAP Auth and pass the authentication cookie/token to Reporting Services using URL access or SOAP APIs. This is for SSO part and probably the only tricky part. Your custom Auth extension should be equipped to receive Auth cookie/token and setup session. Once this is done, You can do URL access to show the required report in iframe, This would include all rich reporting features to end users. Of course, you need to expose your RS instance to end users just like your Java App would be.

Comment: Hi can you give some more details or examples for Customer authentication of Reporting Services ? Also for extranet do we need to configure anything in Report Manager? I understand there is no IIS dependency in Sql 2008 R2.

Comment: Checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281383.aspx and http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2012%21Security%20Extension%20Sample&referringTitle=Home