# SSRS Printer in Java Application

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, reporting-services, printing

I am working to develop a Java application that will eventually print out SSRS reports developed for specific queries.
The application begins with a form that queries a database for members that fit the parameters and adds the resulting members to a Jlist. From there, the user can select a certain member from the Jlist and have a SSRS report specific to that user displayed in the application. I did not create the SSRS report, I only added parameters to the URL to display the user-specific version. In order to have access to display this report I used JavaFx web browser.

My final task is to be able to print the report with a button on the application frame. The issue is, when I put the report inside of this JavaFx browser, it lost pretty much all of its functionality that it had through an Active X toolbar -- to be exported or even printed.

Obviously looking back on this now, it would have been many times easier to just make this application in MS .net, as that is what the SQL server and reporting tool are built in. Java is not very compatible with this MS visual studio programs.

If anyone has attempted to make an SSRS printer application in Java and has made it all the way through -- I'm all ears. Otherwise, I think it's back to the drawing board. 
Thanks.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/142885/206766

Comment: @CoderHawk do you know of a way to implement sections of VB or C# code in Java? if its not too ridiculously difficult

Comment: i really don't know what is the purpose of implementing vb or c# code in java. you can call the ssrs webservice method from java code to download report in pdf format for printing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940234/how-to-do-a-soap-web-service-call-from-java-class

Comment: @CoderHawk This seems like a better idea you're right I just have to figure out exactly what to do. So should I follow the steps of the SOAP thing?

Comment: yes. try it and post your code here if you have any issues. all the best :)