# SSRS Render reports using JAVA and SOAP Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, sql-server-2008, soap, reporting-services

I am working on a Java Web Application and a Reporting Server using SQL Server and I wanna know if its possible to render Reports from SSRS to my Java Application using the SOAP Web Service.

I am using the [SSRS-API](https://github.com/realityforge/ssrs-api) to get information about my SSRS like folders name, reports name, ... but I am not able to render my reports or upload it in PDF or other extensions.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I used the download function (**downloadReport**) of SSRS api I mentioned above ([SSRS-API](https://github.com/realityforge/ssrs-api)), here is the code of the function :

```
public void downloadReport(final String path, final String filename) {
    final File file = new File(filename);
    final String physicalName = toPhysicalFileName(path);

    info("Downloading Report with symbolic name " + path + " to " + file);

    final byte[] data = _soap.getReportDefinition(physicalName);

    try (final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        out.write(data);
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        final String message = "Failed to download report with symbolic name " + path + " to " + file;
        LOG.warning(message);
        if (file.exists() && !file.delete()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(message + " and failed to delete temporary file", ioe);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(message, ioe);

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the function that I use call this function :

```
public void downloadReport() {
    ssrs.downloadReport('Path/Report name', 'C:\\PATH\\TO\\A\\FOLDER\\REPORT.XML');
}
```

And in the given path (C:/PATH/TO/A/FOLDER/REPORT.XML) I get an XML file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="PercallAnalysisDW">
      <DataSourceReference>Entrepôt de données Percall Analysis</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>3a3e3aa4-c6d6-4b44-80f0-f18a9ecd2eac</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DeliveryMarginCumuleDS">
      <SharedDataSet>
        <SharedDataSetReference>DeliveryMarginCumuleDS</SharedDataSetReference>
      </SharedDataSet>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Date">
          <DataField>Date</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Projet">
          <DataField>Projet</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="LABOR_facturé">
          <DataField>LABOR_facturé</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TL_facturé">
          <DataField>TL_facturé</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Coût_total">
          <DataField>Coût_total</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="DM">
          <DataField>DM</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Revenu">
          <Value>=Fields!LABOR_facturé.Value + Fields!TL_facturé.Value</Value>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
            <TablixBody>
                ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by generating reports with URL, here is the function that allows me to generate reports :

```
public void downloadReportExcel(String path) {
    try {
        String url = "http://" + SSRS_IP + "/ReportServer?/" + path + "&rs:Format=Excel";

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);

        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FacesException(e);
    }
}
```

The function get a path in parameters and redirect me to the server url with 2 parameters:

- ?/path : is the full path (from the root folder) of the report to generate
- rs:Format=Excel : is the format of the generation (here I want to export the report to Excel, but It can take PDF, like : &rs:Format=PDF)

thanks for your help @RussellFox, I will give a try for the .NET solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142690/calling-reporting-services-rdl-in-java-application), but be aware that it's from 2005:
[JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071830/build-ci-sdlc/a-java-proxy-for-ms-sql-server-reporting-services.html). And here's an answer from a similar question on a [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a1c8495c-9f63-4964-8d3b-1dc9575bbe07/report-viewer-control-inside-javaswing-application?forum=sqlreportingservices) board:

> "However, report viewer control is only supported in the .Net
>   application. So it is unlikely to integrate the reports with the java
>   based front end without having to launch new browser pages. My
>   suggestion is to use URL access to the reports in the Web Application.
>   However, if you do so, the report will be opened in the new browser
>   page."

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will take a look to all this and I will give you a feedback

Comment: Hello @RussellFox I edited my question to add what I have done, I can get now the XML description of my report, and I wanna know if you have an idea of how I can convert this file to a report like PDF or EXCEL.